# Trouble with js function: doesn't disable button

Tags: javascript, button, conditional-statements

I'm working on a form of my Business. Everything works okay. Now I'm developing a script so the form is not able to be submitted if any of the inputs is not filled. I wrote the code down, but it's not working and I can't find out why. Could you please help me?
The script at the end compares all of the variables with 0, and if any of them equals 0, it disables the send button.

Here is the full code.

```
<form id="alta_usuario" action="envia_form.php" method="post"><input name="tarifa" type="radio" value="3" /> <b>Llamadas ilimitadas + 3GB 12,68€/mes</b>
<input name="tarifa" id="tarifa" type="radio" value="5" /> <b>Llamadas ilimitadas + 5GB 16,09€/mes</b>
<input name="tarifa" id="tarifa" type="radio" value="10" /> <b>Llamadas ilimitadas + 10GB 16,94€/mes</b>
<input name="tarifa" id="tarifa" type="radio" value="20" /> <b>Llamadas ilimitadas + 20GB 18,65€/mes</b><br>
<input name="bono1" type="checkbox" /> Añade más megas a tu tarifa de contrato. <b> BONO 1 GB 2,55€/mes</b>

<hr />

<strong>RECUERDA QUE...</strong>
<ul>
    <li>La tarjeta SIM que te proporcionamos es gratuita.</li>
    <li>Todos los precios que mostramos son con impuestos incluidos.</li>
    <li>Ninguna de nuestras tarifas tienen permanencia.</li>
    <li>Puedes añadir bonos de voz o datos para ampliar tu tarifa.</li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

<hr />

<center><strong>RELLENA EL FORMULARIO DE ABAJO PARA DARTE DE ALTA CON LA CABRA</strong></center><center></center><center></center><center></center><strong>DATOS PERSONALES</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Nosotros hablamos con tu operador y nos encargamos de la portabilidad.</li>
    <li>No te quedaras sin línea.</li>
    <li>Te enviamos tu pedido con la SIM antes de que se haga la portabilidad de tu línea.</li>
    <li>Para obtener el ICCID de la tarjeta, si usas iPhone pincha <a href="https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT204073">aquí</a> o, si usas Android, pincha <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.ale32thebest.simserialnumber&amp;hl=es">aquí</a> para bajarte una app que te lo indicará.</li>
</ul>

<!--corrector numero telefonico !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function muestra_alerta_numero() {
        var contenedor1 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_numero");
        var contenedor2 = document.getElementById("contenedor_correcto_numero");
        var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
        var tamaño_numero = numero.length;
        if (tamaño_numero == 9) {
            contenedor2.style.display = 'block';
            contenedor1.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            contenedor2.style.display = 'none';
            contenedor1.style.display = 'block';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Tu número</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input maxlength="9" name="numero_origen" id="numero" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:muestra_alerta_numero();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_numero" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>El numero introducido debe tener 9 d&iacute;gitos. Por favor, compru&eacute;balo.</i>
    </font>
</div>
<div id="contenedor_correcto_numero" style="display:none">
    <font color="#229954">
        <i>El n&uacute;mero introducido es correcto.</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector ICC-ID !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_icc_id() {
        var contenedor3 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_icc_id");
        var contenedor4 = document.getElementById("contenedor_correcto_icc_id");
        var icc_id = document.getElementById("iccid").value;
        var tamaño_icc_id = icc_id.length;
        if (tamaño_icc_id == 19) {
            contenedor4.style.display = 'block';
            contenedor3.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            contenedor4.style.display = 'none';
            contenedor3.style.display = 'block';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>ICC-ID a portar</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="icc_id" size="100" id="iccid" type="text" maxlength="19" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_icc_id();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_icc_id" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>El ICC-ID debe tener 19 d&iacute;gitos. Por favor, compru&eacute;balo.</i>
    </font>
</div>
<div id="contenedor_correcto_icc_id" style="display:none">
    <font color="#229954">
        <i>El ICC-ID introducido es correcto.</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector operadora !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_operadora() {
        var contenedor5 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_operadora");
        var operadora = document.getElementById("operadora").value;
        var tamaño_operadora = operadora.length;
        if (tamaño_operadora <= 1) {
            contenedor5.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor5.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Tu operadora actual</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="operadora" id="operadora" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_operadora();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_operadora" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir tu operador actual (Orange, Movistar, Vodafone...)</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector nombre !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_nombre() {
        var contenedor6 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_nombre");
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var tamaño_nombre = nombre.length;
        if (tamaño_nombre <= 2) {
            contenedor6.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor6.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Nombre</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="nombre" id="nombre" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_nombre();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_nombre" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir tu nombre tal y como figura en tu documento de identidad.</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector apellido !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_apellido() {
        var contenedor7 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_apellido");
        var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
        var tamaño_apellido = apellido.length;
        if (tamaño_apellido <= 2) {
            contenedor7.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor7.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Apellido(s)</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="apellidos" id="apellido" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_apellido();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_apellido" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir tu(s) apellido(s) tal y como figura(n) en tu documento de identidad.</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector direccion !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_direccion() {
        var contenedor8 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_direccion");
        var direccion = document.getElementById("direccion").value;
        var tamaño_direccion = direccion.length;
        if (tamaño_direccion <= 2) {
            contenedor8.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor8.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Domicilio</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="direccion" id="direccion" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_direccion();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_direccion" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir un domicilio v&aacute;lido</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector ciudad !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_ciudad() {
        var contenedor9 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_ciudad");
        var ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;
        var tamaño_ciudad = ciudad.length;
        if (tamaño_ciudad <= 3) {
            contenedor9.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor9.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Ciudad</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="ciudad" id="ciudad" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_ciudad();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_ciudad" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir una ciudad v&aacute;lida</i>
    </font>
</div>

<!--corrector email !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_email() {
        var contenedor10 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_email");
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var tamaño_email = email.length;
        if (tamaño_email <= 10) {
            contenedor10.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor10.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Dirección de correo electrónico</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input name="email" id="email" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_email();" />
<div id="contenedor_alerta_email" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Asegúrate de que la direcci&oacute;n de correo que escribes sea correcta. Si detectamos que no lo es, el alta no será posible.</i>
    </font>
</div>

<b>Fecha de nacimiento</b>
<select name="fnac_dia">
<option>Día...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select><select name="fnac_mes">
<option>Mes...</option>
<option value="enero">Enero</option>
<option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
<option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
<option value="abril">Abril</option>
<option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
<option value="junio">Junio</option>
<option value="julio">Julio</option>
<option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
<option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
<option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
<option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
<option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select><select name="fnac_anio">
<option>A&ntilde;o...</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
</select>

<!--corrector id !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_ID() {
        var tipo_id = document.getElementById("tipo_id").value;
        var contenedor11_a = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_NIE");
        var IDE = document.getElementById("numero_id").value;
        var tamaño_id = IDE.length;
        if (tamaño_id < 9){
            contenedor11_a.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor11_a.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };      
</script>
<b>Documento de identidad</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<select name="tipo_id" id="tipo_id">
<option value="DNI">DNI</option>
<option value="NIE">NIE</option>
<option value="CIF">CIF</option>
</select><input maxlength="9" name="numero_id" id="numero_id" size="10" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_ID();" />

<div id="contenedor_alerta_NIE" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Debes introducir una identificaci&oacute; v&aacute;lida, sin tener en cuenta guiones. Por ejemplo: X1234567J, B12345678 ó 12345678R </i>
    </font>
</div>

&nbsp;

<b>TUS DATOS BANCARIOS</b>
Tu número de cuenta para pagar las facturas mensuales debe cumplir los siguientes requisitos:
<ul>
    <li>El titular de la cuenta debe ser el mismo de la línea.</li>
    <li>Debe ser una cuenta válida que admita y tenga domiciliaciones vigentes.</li>
    <li>Si tienes otra línea de contrato, tiene que estar domiciliada en la misma cuenta.</li>
    <li>Ordenas a la entidad bancaria que a partir de ahora y hasta nueva orden, atienda con cargo a la cuenta señalada más abajo los pagos a favor de PRIORGAME S.L. (NetService) que le notifiquemos.</li>
</ul>
&nbsp;
<!--corrector iban !-->
<script language="javascript">
    function corrector_iban() {
        var contenedor12 = document.getElementById("contenedor_alerta_iban");
        var iban = document.getElementById("iban").value;
        var tamaño_iban = iban.length;
        if (tamaño_iban != 24) {
            contenedor12.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            contenedor12.style.display = 'none';
        };
    };
</script>
<b>Número de IBAN</b><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
<input maxlength="24" name="iban" id="iban" size="100" type="text" onKeyUp="javascript:corrector_iban();" /><br><br>
<div id="contenedor_alerta_iban" style="display:none">
    <font color="#ff0000">
        <i>Aseg&uacute;rate de que el IBAN introducido es correcto</i>
    </font>
</div>
&nbsp;
<p />

<script language="javascript">
    function habilitar_boton() {
        var detector_tarifa = document.getElementById("tarifa").value.length;
        var detector_numero = document.getElementById("numero").value.length;
        var detector_iccid = document.getElementById("iccid").value.length;
        var detector_operadora = document.getElementById("operadora").value.length;
        var detector_nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value.length;
        var detector_apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value.length;
        var detector_direccion = document.getElementById("direccion").value.length;
        var detector_ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value.length;
        var detector_email = document.getElementById("email").value.length;
        var detector_numero_id = document.getElementById("numero_id").value.length;
        var detector_iban = document.getElementById("iban").value.length;

        //Localizamos el boton "Enviar Formulario" y asignamos su dirección (byId) a una variable. Además,
        //asignamos a una variable el atributo "disabled" para activar o desactivar el botón segun
        //se cumpla, o no, la condición.
        var boton_submit_form = document.getElementById("boton_enviar").disabled;

        //Comenzamos con el procedimiento que ha de seguir la función. Lo que estamos haciendo con ella es
        //comparar todos los length de los inputs con 0. Si es igual a cero, llevaremos a cabo las acciones 
        //arriba definidas.
        if (detector_tarifa == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_numero == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_iccid == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_operadora == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_nombre == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_apellido == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_direccion == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_ciudad == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_email == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_numero_id == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else if (detector_iban == 0){
            boton_submit_form = true;
        } else {
            boton_submit_form = false;
        };
    };      
</script>

<input type="submit" id="boton_enviar" value="Enviar formulario" onMouseOver="javascript:habilitar_boton();" />


</form>
```

Comment: Use `jquery validation plugin` [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: add your `html` code also

Comment: @Dr.Strange It doesn't seem that he is using jQuery.

Comment: Please only post relevant code.

Comment: Either way there is absolutely no need to use `jquery` for this. It's completely unnecessary for what the author is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is because when you execute this line of code:

```
var boton_submit_form = document.getElementById("boton_enviar").disabled;
```

You are storing the boolean value of whether the button is disabled or not in the `boton_submit_form` variable. This ends up being just a `boolean` storage. It has no reference as to where that boolean came from or what UI object you referenced.

So then, further on, when you do `boton_submit_form = true;` it merely changes that boolean value but, again, it's not referenced to anything and so the button remains enabled.

What you should do is as follows:

```
var boton_submit_form = document.getElementById("boton_enviar");
```

And then, in your if / else if statements you can enable and disable the button as follows:

```
boton_submit_form.disabled = false; // To keep the button enabled
boton_submit_form.disabled = true;  // To disable the button
```